# iOS app consuming RESTful webservice for authentication

Tags: ios7, app-store, appstore-approval

I am developing an app for iOS. I am planning to publish this app in app-store as free app. I would like to authorize app users via outside RESTful webservice. Is this practice against any Apple official guidelines and can be not approved by Apple app review?

Comment: Do you mean that you will have a separate login (on a website or something) where the users set up their accounts and pay you? And are you referring to the fact that Apple might want at cut of that $?

Comment: The login information will be distributed to a closed group of clients via other channels.

Comment: Will the app provide anything  for someone that doesn't have an account? Is there a "public" mode?

Comment: No. User will not be able to pass the first screen without login information.

Comment: OK. Got it. In my experience you could get rejected. We built an app once that did basically the same thing, but we included a "public" mode. It was approved and released to the App Store. We believe the "public" mode allowed Apple to test the application and ignore the fact that there was an alternative login process that provided deeper functionality.

Comment: It sounds more like you should be looking at an enterprise deployment, not an app store deployment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple store guidelines and not programming.

Comment: Is there a place on stack exchange where this question will be valid?

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Review Guidelines 11.1 states:

> Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with
>   mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected.

It sounds clear, but I believe it is open to interpretation on behalf of their reviewers. My company has produced an app exactly as you describe and it not only passed but has been versioned up very recently. Like yours, this app consumes a web service and while the launch screen is public facing, the user must immediately authenticate on the screen after that to go any further.

Our app was not a good candidate for the enterprise store model, since the intention is to distribute to customers, not employees.

Also, and perhaps most telling, when you prepare to upload your binary the iTunes Connect portal has a place for you to enter demo account credentials for the testers to access protected content in your app. So I think you're OK. Screencap below taken from iTunes Connect.

[image: iTunes Connect]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Apparently, when submitting your app you can provide demo account information (@erikr98), implying that an app like yours could be tested by Apple and be approved in the store. I've seen apps like this and worked on them before, but was under the impression that you also had to provide some sort of functionality in the app outside of your "pay wall."

....

I think the answer is maybe. It sounds like you're hovering the line between a public app and an enterprise app. I'm going to assume your question could be rephrased like this:

> "I make money from my customers through an existing process (probably on the web) and I want to allow them to use that functionality on iOS without giving 1/3 of that money to Apple via a paid-app or through In-App Purchase. If I build a free app and provide my current customers access to its content via their existing accounts (and through a login process) will Apple reject it?"

[Apple's App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies), Section 11, clearly states that if you allow users to upgrade the content, unlock features or abilities, or purchase content through your application, that purchase must be done through In-App Purchase.

However, in my experience I have found that Apple will not reject an application if it provides value to everyone, not just those with an account. If you provide some sort of benefit for someone without an account you stand a much better chance. In my case we had, 5 features available to the people without an account, and 10 features available for those that could login. Our app was approved and released to the App Store. This was last year.

Also, think about this from a reviewer's perspective at Apple: When you sit down to review an app, its probably not a good sign that you can't access any part of the app without a user name and password.

Look at the model that the newspapers use. Washington Post, for example, has a free app with a $15 In-App purchase that provides you access to their content. You get a limited number of free articles, first, though. See, they provide content for everyone even if on a limited basis. You can also sign into the application, which unlocks all content, if you already have a paying account.

Comment: I consulted with my colleague and he in similar case provided apple workers with login information that allowed them to test the app. Have you ever heard about such practice?

Comment: I haven't heard of such a thing, but I wouldn't rule it out. I have to assume if there are apps in the App Store that require credentials (and I have seen them) there must be some way to supply them to Apple during the review process.

Comment: There is, it is listed under Contact Information when you submit the app. You can provide notes directly to Apple as well as optional "Demo Account Information" credentials.

Comment: @erikr98. I didn't know that. I would add this information, and maybe a screen shot to your answer.